# Fast alter column NVARCHAR(4000) to NVARCHAR(260)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a performance problem with very large memory grants handling this table with a couple of `NVARCHAR(4000)` columns. Thing is these columns are never larger than `NVARCHAR(260)`.

Using

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [col] NVARCHAR(260) NULL
```

results in SQL Server rewriting the entire table, which is billions of rows, only to change nothing, isn't an option. Increasing the column width doesn't have this problem, but decreasing it does.

I have tried creating a constraint `CHECK (DATALENGTH([col]) <= 520)` or `CHECK (LEN([col]) <= 260)` and SQL Server still decides to re-write the entire table.

Is there any way to alter the column data type as a metadata-only operation? Without the expense of rewriting the entire table?

Comment: You can try creating a copy of the table with the same structure named t1 with the requested column  length, copy in 10000 rows at a time into the new table and then when the table is copied drop the original and recreate indexes and permissions on the t1 table and then rename the table to the original name.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Well aware. And that still rewrites the entire table.

Comment: TRY_PARSE ... have you tried that. Handles double digit million recs without issue on 2017 server for me no issues.

Comment: @junketsu `TRY_PARSE` only works on numbers, but a constraint with `TRY_CAST` also doesn't work.

Comment: One option would be to bulk copy out the table and bulk copy in to a new table with correct column definition. It is a fast operation with reduced logging. You should read up on bcp to use it to best suit your needs.

Comment: i suspect that SQL Server does the add column in a multi-step, slow approach. You may try (on a ten million row scratch table) with my approach and built in approach to see which is faster.

Comment: If you change a column  in SSMS by using the GUI it copies the table to a work table with the new col length and follows what I suggested.  This is where I got it from. But until you test both approaches you won't know which is faster. By the way it escalates to a table lock on the target table.

Comment: Try_parse will help with avoiding crashes but will slow it up drastically (1-10 times slower). User is asking what is the fastest way to do this.

Comment: The user is asking for an alternative to recreating the entire table. However, I don't think this is possible in SQL Server. The main issue seems to be that there are billions of rows in one table. If not all of it is still relevant, you might try to permanently offload most of that into archive tables if possible. I know SQL Server tends to struggle even in the tens of millions of rows. That sounds like a nightmare. Best of luck.